# How to set compiler symbols in unit test, or how to detect running unit test?

Tags: c#, testing, symbols

I want to run some tests on SomeProject, so I have a unit test project. But the classes I'm trying to run tests on have some logging capabilities built in, and I'd like to just disable those when unit testing.

If I set something like `UNITTEST` compiler symbol on the test project, that symbol doesn't carry over into the other project. So `[Conditional]` and `#if UNITTEST` don't work.

How can I make some classes aware that they're running as part of a unit test, in order to skip unnecessary stuff - specifically unnecessary logging?

Comment: Use a decent logging framework (eg log4net), and disable logging at a config level, rather than trying to remove actual code.  If you're changing the code you're unit testing, you're arguably not testing it properly.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Logging is currently going through System.Trace. How can it be disabled at a config level, even if using log4net or anything else, if compiler symbols are ignored?

Comment: Log4net can be (re)configured at runtime by code if necessary - ie your test harnesses can configure it off

Comment: So you're saying I can create a static class with a static bool, and use that at runtime to disable calls to Trace.WriteLine. That will work, but it would be nice to avoid so many runtime checks, it would be good to let the compiler exclude code that we know is unnecessary at compile time. So the only solution seems to be, create a new solution configuration "DebugUnitTesting" that defines a compiler symbol in all relevant projects, and then use ```[Conditional]``` and/or ```#if``` as appropriate.